# К тому же - является ли в каких-нибудь случаях вводными словами?

Tags: синтаксис

Является ли вводным словом выражение "к тому же" в предложении: К тому же только сам человек может понять, что он счастлив.

Answer (score 1):

В примере обособление не нужно. Тут даже вопрос так не стоит.

Если же Вас прежде всего интересует вопрос, вынесенный в заголовок, то да, можно себе представить конструкцию, в которой "к тому же" будет вполне себе вводным словом. Особенно если исходить из определения вводного слова,а не из того, что "вводное" равно "обособляемое". Достаточно, например, перенести в Вашем примере "к тому же", скажем, после "может". Смысл такой фразы может быть несколько разным при трактовке "к тому же" вводным или членом предложения. Эту особенность автор может передать обособлением или отсутствием его.

Answer (score 1):

Процитирую подробную статью с примерами из словаря-справочника вводных слов O.A. Остроумовой и О.Д. Фрамполь.

**К TOMV ЖЕ (Ж)**, союз.

1. Редко вводное, встречаются случаи только авторского
   пользования выражения к тому же в качестве вводного
   слова для выражения субъективного отношения к какому-либо
   факту при желании подчеркнуть его значимость: *К тому же,
   повествование ее, в строгом смысле, бессюжетно и держится,
   ровным образом, энергией монолога* (И. Бродский); *К тому
   же, вы сейчас как начнете рассказывать, перестаете быть
   философом* (Ф. Достоевский); *К тому же, есть ведь еще и
   старые, которые ты не успел посмотреть* (А. Алексин); *К тому
   же, каждый день шел снег, и каждое утро приходилось, прежде
   чем приступить к самой работе, порядочно поработать
   лопатой* (М. Пришвин). **Не рекомендуется использовать союз *к
   тому же* в качестве вводного слова.**
2. Обычно невводное, употребляется в функции союза (=
   да еще, вдобавок), не обособляется: *В результате она так и
   не получила диплома. К тому же в двадцать пять лет стала
   матерью-одиночкой* (С. Довлатов); *Об этой легкости возникновения творческого состояния у людей гениальных и к тому
   же обладающих даром импровизации упоминают многие писатели* (К. Паустовский); *Постовой Хахалин без надобности
   израсходовал боезапас, к тому же пьян был* (В. Астафьев).